# JetBrains Rider: How to attach to elevated permissions process running locally?

Tags: rider

I am using JetBrains Rider on Linux to debug some .NET core services. I have launched Rider without `sudo` permissions since my code source tree is all under my local user, but yet the installed services are running under `root` permissions.

Right now I'm in a predicament where in order to attach to the running processes, I have to launch a new Rider instance using `sudo`, but that then messes up the source code tree. Overall, this is a huge pain.

I would like to be able to attach to the elevated-permission service via an instance of Rider that is launched without `sudo`. I think the below is the way to do it: Run --> Attach to Remote Process, which brings up the below popup:

[image]

However, the problem with this popup is that if I click the arrow on `root@localhost:22`, then it shows no processes to attach to. Yet, the 4 processes are there that I would like to attach to (in the screenshot, they are 14949-14952). **How can I get "no processes to attach to" to list the 4 processes in question? I have seen this done before by another developer, just think I'm missing something.** Also, I'm 100% sure I know the root password.